# How to find the last value in a column in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I am tracking rooms booked in a hotel on a daily basis in Excel.  Every day I input the number of rooms booked in a column to show a trend of pick up over a period.  I'd like to return the value of the last entry in a column.

I would post a picture to illustrate, but apparently you have to be at a certain level.

Answer (score 5):

Sure use this (for numbers) -

```
=VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,B:B,1)
```

Change `B:B` to whatever column you're using.

or this (for text) -

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),B:B)
```

Comment: The `LOOKUP(2,1/...` approach slows down my spreadsheets a lot for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/return-the-last-item-in-an-excel-column/)):

```
=INDEX(column, COUNTA(column), 1)
```

> For instance, to return the last value in column A, you'd use the
>   expression
>
> =INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A), 1)

Comment: This works, but it's a faster calculation to no use an array formula.

Comment: This is not invariably the case :) Take a look: http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeede.htm. VLOOKUP is slightly faster (approx. 5%), simpler and uses less memory than a combination of MATCH and INDEX or OFFSET.
However the additional flexibility offered by MATCH and INDEX often allows you to make significant timesaving compared to VLOOKUP.

Comment: True, but `index()` is also volatile (for WS structure changes, not cell changes). [source](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) - download the zip and watch the volatility if adding/removing a row or column.

Comment: A good point :)

Comment: Probably no difference between the two in this particular application, assuming the amount of data isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

*You may use any on these formulas:*

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),A:A)

=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(A1:A32)),A1:A32)
```